# Ionic 4 and Firebase page not found

Tags: firebase, service-worker, firebase-hosting, ionic4

I recently started an Ionic 4 project and added service woker with the `$ ng add @angular/pwa --project app` command and hosted it on the firebase. It works beautiful and perfect, but when I give a `Ctrl + F5` on the page or do an audit with`Lighthouse` it returns me page not found and only works again, if I go to the url and remove `/home`, leaving only the url base, so he can install the service worker and works normally, if in case I do not do the above procedure :D. If I can get an answer, I'll be very grateful.

I thank the attention.

**Note: Sorry for my English, I'm Brazilian and I'm not fluent.**

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem using Ionic 4 with `@angular/pwa`.
The solution was to add the following rewrite to the file `firebase.json`:

```
"rewrites": [{
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
}]
```

So that the `firebase.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "www",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
    }]
  }
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :D